# I am not able to loop through the whole row in excel using python

Tags: python, pandas

I am have two excels, I am trying to take second column values from exel1 and placing the values in second column by joining them with Underscore in excel2

Excel1:

| Word | Variable |
| --- | --- |
| identifier | id |
| user | us |
| phone | ph |
| number | num |
| phone number | pn |

Excel2:

| Word | Variable Should be |
| --- | --- |
| user identifier | us_id |
| user phone number | us_pn |
| identifier number | id_num |

I am not getting whole row while looping.

```
     import pandas as pd
     import os

     file1= 'C:/Users/madhu/Desktop/Excel1.xlsx'
     file2= 'C:/Users/madhu/Desktop/Book1.xlsx'

     df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
     df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)

     #df1.to_dict()
     #df2.to_dict()
     var=[]
     print(df1)
     print(df2)
     for row,col in range(len(df1)):
     for row1,col in range(len(df2)):
     if row.isspace() == True:
         var.append(df1[row])
         return '_'.join(var)
     elif row == row1:
         var.append(df1[row])
         return '_'.join(var)
     else:
         pass
```

Can anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: It is very hard to tell what your problem is. Your code will not run as it stands because the indentation is wrong. And please explain what output you are getting and what output you expect. That said, it appears your function is `return`ing after processing the first row of the data. Your function should complete the loops without returning, and then do `return var` because it appears the calling code is expecting a list back.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that for "user phone number" you need "us_pn" as a variable. I am also assuming that the code does not need to return any values.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

file1= 'C:/Users/madhu/Desktop/Excel1.xlsx'
file2= 'C:/Users/madhu/Desktop/Book1.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)

# Uncomment the following piece of code if the excel files have nan.
# df2.fillna('0', inplace=True)

print(df2)

for row2 in df2.values:
    word_list = list(row2[0].split(' '))
    
    # This is to handle the special case of 'user phone number'
    # with output of 'us_pn'. 
    # If the desired output is otherwise
    # 'us_ph_num', then this piece of code is not needed.
    if 'phone number' in row2[0]:
        word_list[word_list.index('phone')] = 'phone number'
        word_list[word_list.index('number')] = ''
    
    var_list = []
    for word in word_list:
        for row1 in df1.values:
            if word == row1[0]:
                var_list.append(row1[1])
    row2[1] = "_".join(var_list)
```

If there is anything wrong with my assumptions, then do let me know and I will fix the code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC! Create a dict out of df1 and map for split items(S1 and S2) from df2. Refer below code

```
df1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)

Map = dict(zip(df1.Word, df1.Variable))

pat='('+'|'.join(Map.keys())+')'
df2['S1']= df2['Word'].str.extract(pat=pat,expand=False).fillna('')
df2['S2'] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.Word.replace(x['S1'],''), axis =1)

df2['S2'] = df2['S2'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
cols = ['S1', 'S2']

for col in cols:
    df2[col] = df2[col].replace(Map)

df2['Variable Should be'] = df2['S1'] +'_'+ df2['S2']
df2.drop(columns = ['S1', 'S2'], inplace = True)
```